# How to handle monthly and yearly values

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a Fact table that holds what are more or less, sales goals.  The ETL process that populates it, generates 12 "weighted" values into seperate rows, one per month.  Each row however, also includes a field that holds the yearly value. I do this with unpivot.  This all works.  Now Im trying to get at this data in the cube with an SSRS report.  The problem seems to be that I can query and see the results that include either the yearly goal values or the monthly, weighted values, but not both in the same set.

[update for fact table details]
My Fact table looks something like this:

```
FK_Account
FK_User
Target
Projected
GoalYear
FK_DateKey
FK_Dept
MonthlyWeightedTarget
MonthlyWeightedProjected
```

When I load this fact table via the ETL, I get the date key associated with each monthly value (MonthlyWeightedTarget).  That will be 12 seperate records, but each one will have the same yearly value.  Im not including next years value as a seperate column, because there are seperate records already associated with that year.

Basically, the users define a set of goals associated with a given year.  Then I am applying a "weighting" to generate 12 seperate "monthly" records, which total up to the yearly target goal.  Hope this makes sense.

What I need to see is something like this result:

```
Account Name
YTDgoal
YearGoal
NextYrGoal
```

I created a calculated member for the NextYrGoal, but now Im not sure I even need it.

What would be a good approach for handling the above (getting the ytd, yearly and next year values) ?

If I was getting at these values with TSQL, I would sum on the monthly values, and just include the associated yearly and next years values, grouping by account, year-goal, next-year-goal

Comment: Please clarify, do you have a fact table with monthly sales goal, yearly sales goal and next year per row? show the T-SQL query you are trying

Comment: A common practice is to create a Time Calculations dimension

Comment: Well an example scenario would be, for a given account, show the month-todate goal value (eg jan 1 thru aug 1 2015), along with the year end goal (all of 2015) and next years (2016) yearly goal, all on one line.  How would a time dimension help over and above just a date dimension?